# trigger a hive query and show incremental data on UI

Tags: node.js, hadoop, hive

I need to build a UI tool where people can enter an expression (e.g gender = male & no. of transactions > 10) and on submitting the expression, internally a hive query gets fired and then I need to show the output in some way (like a count that gets updated after every 10 seconds as the query is returning results)

Is it possible to do this using a node front end and a hive query in the backend ? Is the resultset returned by hive query accessible as soon as the results start coming in ( i forgot the term for this but it is possible for normal SQL queries on some dbs)

Is there any framework for such things that I can reuse?

Answer (score 0):

The typical option that you should use is to use Hive JDBC client provided the Hive's JDBC Thrift server is running in you environment. It would be as similar as querying the usual rdbms databases using JDBC clients.

But not sure about with node.js, but the below project speaks about connecting and querying the Hive tables from node.js environment.

https://github.com/tagomoris/shib

Try this out and please share us your observations.

Comment: Went the same way as you suggested, implemented a REST service on java which takes the input and fires a HIVE query through JDBC client and sends the response back when the entire qurey results are back. Trying to see if I can optimize it (or send some incremental progress stats back)